# Trouble using a prompt with object literal (JS)(New to coding)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prompt

I'm new to coding and JS so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question. I have an object literal named listA, which has various keys:values in it. I am trying to have the code prompt to the user all of the items (keys:values) in the object literal, and allow the user to input a response, which would get stored in another variable.

First off, I have the object literal to start off with:

```js
var listA = {
"Pizza" : 15,
"Salad" : 5,
"Fries" : 6,
"Soda" : 2
};
```

I've tried many things all along the lines of:

```js
var choice = prompt("What do you want?  \n" + listA);
```

This was in hopes it would prompt the user all of the items (`"Pizza" : 15, "Salad" : 5,"Fries" : 6,"Soda" : 2,`) and the user would input a response.

The exact problem is that whenever the code goes to prompt, it prompts `[object]` instead of all of the items inside the object literal (\\ the menu items)
[image]

(\\the image above is what exactly it is currently prompting to the user, which is the problem I'm trying to fix)

*Sorry if I didn't ask the question great and/or didn't use stack overflow correctly, I'm new to coding (JS), and stack overflow

Comment: Welcome @daviddunec! A good question will include some code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Also, see JSON.stringify

Comment: You need to specify to the prompt how you want to display and format its keys and values.

Comment: How would I do that? @user1599011

Comment: Research Object literals. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: That's how an object looks like in itself. `prompt("What do you want?  \n" + JSON.stringify(listA))` could be somewhat dirty, but step forward.

Comment: Then a next one `prompt("What do you want?\n"+Object.entries(listA).map(([x,y])=>x.toString()+":"+y.toString()).join(", "))`.

Comment: ngl i have not a clue in the world what JSON is or how to use it. @tevemadar

Comment: Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) is a wonderful resource https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/